# Sending email from android app using gmail smtp

Tags: android, email, smtp

I am using the code from this tutorial [javapapers email app](http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/)

I am getting these errors

```
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926): null
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):        javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at   com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.GMail.sendEmail(GMail.java:82)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.SendMailTask.doInBackground(SendMailTask.java:39)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-05 01:33:25.649: E/SendMailTask(1926):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and this

```
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): Process: com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail, PID: 1926
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.SendMailTask.onProgressUpdate(SendMailTask.java:51)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:648)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-05 01:33:25.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1926):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code is below. In Gmail.java class Inside sendEmail method at this line javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException is coming

> transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);

```
public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    System.out.println("emailHost="+emailHost);
    System.out.println("fromEmail="+fromEmail);
    System.out.println("fromPassword="+fromPassword);

    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
}
```

In SendMailTask.java class I am getting NullPointerException at this line

> statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

```
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());
}
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Please put the actual code you are using in the question and tell us where it is failing. Just providing a link is useless in the event that the linked content is changed/removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the exact **email id and password** of the gmail account from which you need to send the mail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Java part but I do know about smtp and that what you haven't included is either of the smtp ports that allows Gmail to parse it's code into an email editor follow this link from Google about smtp and rewrite you code accordingly. Link = https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en